# Loop through variables to melt in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, melt

My current data set has a lot of variables, each looking like

```
year    place1    place2
1999    1.1       7.8
...
```

And I want each variable to be melted by year. I wonder why the following code is not working.

```
# define function 
my.melt <- function(x){
  x <- melt(x, id.vars=c('year'), 
  variable.name='place')
}
```

Then I loop through my variables with my function:

```
# loop through
var.names=list(var1, var2)
for (i in 1:length(var.names)){
var.names[i] <- my.melt(var.names[i])
}
```

Using this loop, nothing is changed. However, when I try

```
var1 <- my.melt(var1)
```

It works and my `var1` is reshaped. So I assume my function is ok. Why is the loop not working?

Note: I have also tried `lapply`; it also didn't work as I anticipated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try `lapply(var.names, my.melt)` it should work, also `return x` in `my.melt`

Answer (score 0):

One thing to change in the loop is change `[` to `[[` and also the `my.melt` should return the 'x'

```
my.melt <- function(x){
  x <- melt(x, id.vars=c('year'), 
  variable.name='place')
  x
}

var.names=list(var1, var2)
for (i in 1:length(var.names)){
  var.names[[i]] <- my.melt(var.names[[i]]) 
 }
```

But, this can be also done with `lapply`

```
 list2env(setNames(lapply(var.names, my.melt), paste0("var", 1:2)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

#### data

```
var1 <- structure(list(year = 1999:2000, place1 = c(1.1, 1.5), place2 = c(7.8, 
  7.3)), .Names = c("year", "place1", "place2"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -2L))

var2 <- structure(list(year = 1999:2000, place1 = c(1.1, 1.7), place2 = c(8.3, 
 7.3)), .Names = c("year", "place1", "place2"),
  row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is there a way to replace my old variables with the reshaped variable? Because right now, if I want the second variable, I have to use `lapply(var.names, my.melt)[[2]]`; is there a way to replace old `var2` with the new (reshaped) `var2`? I have upvoted your answer but it will probably take a while for the system to show up.

Comment: @Shane I updated with `list2env`, but it is better to keep it in a `list` and not change anything in the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to my latest comment,

```
# loop through
reshape <- lapply(var.names, my.melt)
```

Now, I `cbind()` all my data:

```
datalist = list() # create empty list
for (i in 1:100) {
  datalist[[i]] <- reshape[[i]]
}
merge <- do.call(cbind, datalist)
merge <- subset(merge, select = c(seq(3, 300, by = 3)))
names(merge) <- c(var.names)
```

Definitely not the smartest way -- but it works.